# Can Debug.Assert be set to just throw an exception instead of popping up a window in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'd like an exception to be thrown and the editor to jump to the place whenever an assertion fails in my C# application. But an abort/retry/ignore message box pops up instead. Is there a way to control this behaviour?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e63efys0.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You could add a custom TraceListener which throws an exception on either of the `.Fail()` methods:

```
public class ThrowListener : TextWriterTraceListener
{
    public override void Fail(string message)
    {
        throw new Exception(message);
    }

    public override void Fail(string message, string detailMessage)
    {
        throw new Exception(message);
    }
}
```

I would probably derive your own Exception type which takes both a message and detailMessage and so it's more obvious where the exception's coming from.

You will have to step up the call stack to the .Assert() call as the debugger will likely take you straight to the `throw`.

You can add it like this:

```
Debug.Listeners.Insert(0, new ThrowListener());
```

Answer (score 2):

Not directly: That is what Debug.Assert does. See the documentation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.aspx

Perhaps you want to use something other than Debug.Assert?  Such as simply throwing an exception if it can't be handled, or by invoking some application-defined onError handler when desired?

Alternatively, you may be able to get what you want by adding a listener and hooking into that listener. See the documentation.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: The documentation states that the role of Assert is to show a message containing the callstack. Ie, that's the primary purpose. (Eg: "Checks for a condition; if the condition is false, displays a message box that shows the call stack.")  I am happy to change my answer, but I would like to know exactly why it's wrong. (Do note that I consider the question *title* as being part of the question)

Comment: @Arafangion I have to agree with you.  I wouldn't say Debug.Assert can be set to throw, as that implied inbuilt functionality.  It can kind of be hacked to throw, but you did mention that.  I didn't go into it as you'd already answered before I'd finished my code example.

Comment: "No, it can't." is not true - you can report them whatever way you want with custom listeners. I.e. it is useful in case of unit tests. I agree that default behavior is to show message, but it definitely not set in stone behavior.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Good point, I've modified the answer to make it more correct; although it now feels a bit 'silly'. (Not by default? Obviously, hence the reasonable request to change it somehow).